# How to split an array into two different arrays without using loop?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array which contain of value shown below

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "11"
  1 => "A_15"
]
```

How can i split it into 2 arrays?

```
//example
array1 store 11
array2 store 15
```

I am using A_ as indication to determine which array should store which value.

What i tried

```
$arr1 = array_filter($myArr, function($v) { return strpos($v, 'A_') === false; });
$arr2 = array_filter($myArr, function($v) { return strpos($v, 'A_') !== false; });
```

How can i store the value by removing the A_ infront?

Or any better way to do it without using looping?

Comment: That is one funky looking array.

Comment: Have you tried `array_slice`?

Comment: `array_filter` is some sort of a loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$arr = ["A_15","11"];

sort($arr);                        //Sort the array, which means string starts with letters will go last (A_)
list($arr1, $arr2) = $arr;         //Assign the first element to $arr1, 2nd elemnt to $arr2

$arr2 = substr($arr2, 2);          //Remove the first 2 characters "A_"
```

This will result to:

```
$arr1 = 11
$arr2 = 15
```

Doc: [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php),  [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the .splice() method to split based on situational logic:

```
var array1=[11,15];
var array2=array1.splice(0,1);
```

OR

```
var array1=[11,15,1,2,3,4];
var array2=array1.splice(0,3);
```

In both cases array2 will holds first part and array1 will have second part.

Answer (score 0):

To split your values into 2 arrays, you might use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with [ltrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) to remove the `A_` prefix from the value and then use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to chunk an array into arrays.

```
$myArr = ['11', 'A_15'];
$myArr = array_chunk(array_map(function($x) { return ltrim($x, 'A_');}, $myArr), 1);
list($a1, $a2) = $myArr;
var_dump($a1);
var_dump($a2);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ptPJh)

That will give you 2 arrays:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "11"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "15"
}
```